# Why does it give me an output of 49?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char i=49;
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the output is 49?

I am using `%d` to print a character, whereas my character declaration is also wrong.

Comment: "%d" says print an integer, You didn't feed it an integer, so it's doing the best it can. Generally not a good thing to do, but [variadic promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments) saves your bacon here.

Comment: `char` is an integer type, and though typically narrower than `int` it's converted to `int` when passed to a function like `printf()` with a variable argument list.

Comment: All the above comment should be an answer, not a comment...

Comment: please read the manual for `printf` - i.e. https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Answer (score 1):

In C a `char` means the same thing as a *byte*; it is the smallest addressable piece of memory, and also a smallest of integer types. 49 is an *integer constant* of type `int` having the value `49`. `'1'` is a character constant, that also has type `int`! And on ASCII systems`'1'` as the value 49 (the ASCII code of character `1`).

`printf` conversion specifier `%d` expects the corresponding argument to be an `int`, whose value is then printed in decimal notation. The remaining arguments after the format string are subject to *default argument promotions*; each integer type smaller than `int` is promoted to an `int`; and `float` is promoted to `double`. Since `i` has an integer type smaller than `int`, its value (49) is now promoted to an int and to `printf` it looks exactly the same as if any other integer value 49 was given.

To print the *character* whose character code is `49`, you need to use the `%c` conversion specifier; `printf` will then output `1`, which is the character by code 49; even now, the argument is promoted to `int`, and `printf` internally converts that value to an **`unsigned char`**, which then will be output [(source)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8):

> c
>
> [...] the `int` argument is converted to an unsigned char, and the resulting character is written. [...]

---

Addendum: in code

```
char i = 49.012;
printf("%f", i);
```

`49.012` is a value of type `double`; this is converted to char-range integer by chopping the decimals, thus the value stored in `i` is *yet* again 49; which one can prove by printing it with `%d`. Now, `%f` expects that the corresponding argument is of type `double` but `i` is converted to an `int` instead; using an argument of wrong type in call to `printf` has *undefined behaviour*, i.e. anything can happen. If one compiles with `gcc -Wall`, the following error is produced:

> warning: format `%f` expects argument of type `double`, but argument 2 has type `int` [-Wformat=]

Comment: when I write char i=49.012 and use printf("%f",i); why the %f didn't print its float value ....it gives me answer 0.00000?why its so?

Comment: @AnkitArora added

Comment: what added.plz explain me in detail i am new in c programming

Comment: @AnkitArora the *addendum*

Answer (score 0):

Updating answer based on comments.

char is an `integer` type, and you assign 49 to this integer type. The %d conversion specifier prints the value of an integer;

```
char i=49;
```

If you print using `"%c"` you can see the corresponding character of ascii value 49 ie `1`

Since you are using `"%d"` you get the integer value itself.

You can try this

```
char i='1';
```

Now try `printf("%d",i);`
You will get `49`

Comment: @DavidBowling I agree with you.  What I meant was when we assign an integer value to a char type, ascii character corresponding to that integer will be assigned to that variable.

Comment: what does this concept in c called? ok what happens when we use char i=49; int i=59 and then printf("%d",i);

Comment: @DavidBowling   but when I write char i=49.012 and use printf("%f",i);                    why the %f didn't print its float value ....it gives me answer 0.00000?why its so?

Answer (score 0):

%d,%c,%o,%x... these are called format specifier. it will decide which type of output you want.

in your example, you assigned 49 to i and saying to compiler that you want the output in decimal.

if you try to print the same by substituting %d with %c, then it will print

1 because it assumes the output should be print in the form of char equivalent of the given number

where in ASCII table 49 is 1

and FYI

in the implementation of printf function they will deal '%' symbol followed by the character as special case

if the followed character is valid then it will output

%x is hex
%d is decimal
%i is integer
%c is character
%s is string
%f is float
............... etc
you can google "formal specifier in c" there will be plenty of results

hope this info useful to you.

Comment: when I write char i=49.012 and use printf("%f",i); why the %f didn't print its float value ....it gives me answer 0.00000?why its so?